# Update or overwrite in existing chart vba

Tags: excel, vba, graph, excel-charts

Hello everyone i am creating a vba code which graph a chart, my question is: How can i update or overwrite seriescollection or values in my chart created because everytime when i run my sub it creates n graphs if i run the sub n times, or what idea do you recommend me to get my goal?, i appreciate your helping, here is the code:

```
Sub Grafica()
'*** Creación de gráficas
Dim MyChartName As String
Dim CreateChart As Boolean
Dim Graph As ChartObject
Dim doc As Workbook

Set doc = ThisWorkbook
found = False 'buscador de hojas repetidas

With doc 'examina si en el libro hay hojas repetidas'
    For Each ws In doc.Worksheets 'examina en cada hoja de las que hay en el excel local
        If (LCase(ws.Name) = LCase("Series_Graph")) Then
            found = True
            Set ws = ws 'al hallar condición se fija la hoja existente para colocar valor, (creo que con esto sirve para actualizar)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If (Not found) Then 'en caso la hoja no exista crea una nueva con el nombreasignado por defecto: DATA_nombrehojaexaminada
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count))
        ws.Name = "Series_Graph"
    End If

End With


Set Sheetg = doc.Sheets("Series_Graph") 'Hoja de gráfico
MyChartName = "Gráfica 1"
CreateChart = True

If Sheetg.ChartObjects.count > 0 Then
  For Each Graph In Sheetg.ChartObjects
    If Graph.Name = MyChartName Then
      CreateChart = False
      Set Graph = Sheetg.ChartObjects(MyChartName)
    End If
  Next
End If

If CreateChart = True Then
    Set Graph = Sheetg.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=15, Left:=0, Width:=510.236, Height:=1020.47)
    Graph.Name = MyChartName
End If
With Graph.Chart
    '.SetSourceData rng 'Since we already set the range of cells to be used for chart we have use RNG object here
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "IN-GAP-04" & vbCr & _
                            "Eje " & "A" & vbCr & _
                            "Azimut: " & "268.16" & "°"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .ChartTitle.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 16
    .ChartTitle.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Round(((RanArray1(1)(1)) / 2), 0) * 2
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Round((RanArray1(1)(0) / 2), 0) * 2
    '.SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone
    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Name = "Arial"
    '.Axes(xlXValue).TickLabels.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Rango de precisión"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = RanArray1(0)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = RanArray1(1)
    .SeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .DashStyle = 3 '3 o msoLineRoundDot cualquiera de las 2 expresiones es valida
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'rojo
        .Weight = 2.25
    End With

End With



Debug.Print Graph.Name
'Debug.Print Round((RanArray1(1)(0) / 2), 0) * 2
'Debug.Print Join(RanArray1(1), ",")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have one graph to show, you should delete all current existing graphs, then add one graph which will be the latest one (the updated one).
Add the following lines of code before you start formatting the chart (Picture below)

```
For i = Graph.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
    Graph.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
Next i
```

[image]

If you look at your current code, it adds a new series `".SeriesCollection.NewSeries"`, but you only update the first series (index 1). Therefore, you can delete all series beforehand and when you add a new series by default it will be index 1 and everything should work. Or you can do an if statement to check if a series already exist, if so no need to create a new series.